# Labels on an ExtJS4 Time-Axis

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, date-formatting, extjs-chart

I have a bottom time axis, which is defined as following:

```
{
  "title":"Date",
  "description":"",
  "position":"bottom",
  "type":"Time",
  "fields":["date"],
  "dateFormat":"d.m.Y"
}
```

But all the labels are "NaN.NaN.0NaN"

When I look in the store, the date field is a normal Date object with the right values.
But when I look in the drawLabel function of Axis, `me.labels` has no objects, so nothing gets drawn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a renderer for the time axis:

```
getDateRenderer: function(v) {
    return Ext.util.Format.date(v, 'd.m.Y');
}
```

and here setting it to  it:

```
this.chart.axes.items[2].label.renderer = this.getDateRenderer;
```